# API for setting a property to one of a fixed set of values

Tags: c#, api-design

I'm designing the software API for an electronic device, and one of the features is setting the values of some property.

There is only a bunch of accepted values for any given property, from which the user is expected to select these from a ComboBox in a GUI.

The class is currently designed like this:

```
public class Device
{
    public double[] ValidPropertyValues => new double[] { 1000, 2000, 4000 };

    public double Property { get; set; }
}
```

My main concern is that nothing prevents `Property` to be set to values outside `ValidPropertyValues`, except client code (like the ComboBox example).

Is there a way to *enforce*, with design only - that is, with code in the class itself - that only valid values would be "settable"?

Comment: Couldn't you just use a setter?

Comment: How many valid properties can you have? If it's a small set you can always have an enum.

Comment: Well, technically, a property is part of a class, so code in a property's setter is *code in the class itself*. Why don't you do that?

Comment: Well in practice I already have a setter, just an automatic one. Are you suggesting to put some logic in the setter? Like throwing an exception in case an invalid value is used? Or perhaps have some `bool TrySetProperty(double newValue)` that would return `false` if an invalid value is used?

Comment: @ClaudiuGuiman each device model might have different values from each other, so I cannot anticipate statically those values in order to put them into an `enum`.

Comment: @heltonbiker if each device has it's own set of values I think you should have a public method: bool IsValueSupported(double value) and in the Property setter just throw an InvalidArgumentException if an invalid value is provided. The caller should first call IsValueSupported then set it.

Comment: @ClaudiuGuiman actually that's what `ValidPropertyValues` is all about. Client code is expected to take one of the valid values and use it to set the property, but I'm not sure it is a good design or this type of thing is usually done some other way.

Comment: If you are using WebAPI then I may suggest to check route constraints.

Comment: What if you changed the `Property` to only accept index values into `ValidPropertyValues` - so users of the API can only pick valid values. What do they need to know about/care about when setting `Property` should drive how they do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version:

```
public class Device
{
    private double data;
    public double[] ValidPropertyValues => new double[] { 1000, 2000, 4000 };
    public double Property
    {
        get { return data; }
        set {
            foreach (double val in ValidPropertyValues)
            if (value == val)
            {
                data = value;
                break;
            }
            //if not found, throw some exception
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, add some logic to your setter instead of leaving it automatic.